# Probability that a length $8$ password is made by $2$ digits and $6$ characters

Tags: probability

> You have $10$ digits $(0,1,2,...,9)$ and $26$ characters (from the
>   American alphabet).
>
> Calculate the probability to automatic generate a 8-length password
>   with $2$ digits and $6$ characters.

I know the answer is $ p=\frac{\binom{8}{2}\times10^2\times26^6}{36^8} $ and I know that $\binom{8}{2}$ are the picks where $2$ on $8$ elements are digits.

What I can't understand is why shouldn't I use $\binom{8}{6}$ to say that picks are made with $6$ characters on $8$ elements, instead of $\binom{8}{2}$?

The second question is: if I had to make a password with $1$ digits, $3$ special characters (chosen by $10$ special characters) and $4$ characters, the probability should change in: $ p=\frac{\binom{8}{1}\times\binom{8}{3}\times\binom{8}{4}\times10^1\times10^3\times26^4}{46^8} $?

Comment: $\binom{8}{6}=\frac{8!}{6!2!}=\frac{8!}{2!6!}=\binom{8}{2}$.  You are totally allowed to use $\binom{8}{2}$ instead of $\binom{8}{6}$ or vice versa and the answer will be the same.  In general $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$

Comment: As for the second part of the question, no, it won't be $\binom{8}{1}\binom{8}{3}\binom{8}{4}$, it will instead be $\binom{8}{1,3,4}=\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{4}=\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{4}\binom{1}{1}=\dots=\frac{8!}{1!3!4!}$.  When choosing which slots are used by which category of character, once you have picked the slots for the one category you can no longer use those spots by a different category later on.

Comment: Also, for the last part, it should be $10^1\cdot 10^3\cdot 26^{\color{red}{4}}$, not $26^6$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, great! Thank you for the explanations! You can turn this comments in an answer, you've been very clear!

Comment: Whoops, the last part is a little Ctrl+C Ctrl+V mistake! Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Did you mean to write $3\color{red}{6}^8$ in the denominator for the first probability and $4\color{red}{6}^8$ in the denominator for the second probability?

Comment: ${8 \choose 6} = {8 \choose 2}$.  The result will be exactly the same.

Comment: ${n \choose r}  = { n \choose {n-r}}$.  Mathematically that is clear as ${n \choose r} = \frac {n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ and $r = n - (n-r)$ so $\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!} =\frac{n!}{ (n - (n-r))!(n-r)!} ={n \choose n-r}$.  Logistically, this should be clear as the number of ways to choose to remove $r$ from $n$ must be exactly the same as the number of ways to choose to leave in $n-r$ from $n$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah, I'm sorry! I work with Italian alphabet and I said American one cause of "international reason". I forgot to substitute the values!

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $8 \choose 6$ instead of $8 \choose 2$ just fine.  They are equal.  In general ${n \choose r}={n \choose n-r}$ and your proof is a good one.  For your second question, you should not use ${8 \choose 1}{8 \choose 3}{8 \choose 4}$.  The first $8 \choose 1$ picks which character will be special.  Having chosen that, you have only seven places left for the three digits, so the factor would be $7 \choose 3$.  Having chosen the first two, you have only four places left for four letters, so the overall factor should be ${8 \choose 1}{7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 4}=\frac {8!}{1!3!4!}$

Comment: ${n \choose n-r} = {n \choose r}$ is clear from the definition ${n \choose r} = \frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ and the realization that $n - (n-r) = r$.  But it also becomes clear if you realize choosing r from n to do something is the exact same thing as choosing n-r from n to *not* do something.

Comment: @fleablood:  the bijection is exactly what OP was pointing at.